# How to control android media volume using volume keys

Tags: android, key, media, volume, audio-player, android-music-player

Can anyone provide sample code for adjusting media volume using volume keys, and also it should display a volume alert progress while pressing the keys.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{ 

 if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) { 
   // Do your thing 
   return true;   

} else {
   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 

 }
}
```